# How to sort a cvs file by one field in Java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

How can I sort a cvs file by one field in Java?
For example I want to sort it by the third field
I have a cvs file that looks like this:

```
1951,Jones,5
1984,Smith,7
...
```

I tried using Scanner as such, with a delimiter but I couldn't figure out how to go on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //String data = args[0];
        Scanner s = null;
        String delim = ";";
        try
        {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader (new FileReader("test.csv")));
            List<Integer> three = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            while(s.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(s.next());
                s.useDelimiter(delim);

            }   
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(s != null)
            {
                s.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't know about a "cvs file", but if you're reading a CSV file, use a CSV reader, then load the data into classes, and sort those classes. Instructions for all of that can be found on the web.

Comment: Thank you for commenting but I got stuck and couldn't find anything online

Comment: Which part? Find a CSV library for Java? Using it? Creating a class for the data? Sorting the list of objects? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final String DELIM = ";";
    final int COLUMN_TO_SORT = 2; //First column = 0; Third column = 2.

    List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.csv"))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            records.add(getRecordFromLine(scanner.nextLine(), DELIM));
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    Collections.sort(records, new Comparator<List<String>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(List<String> row1, List<String> row2){
            if(row1.size() > COLUMN_TO_SORT && row2.size() > COLUMN_TO_SORT)
                return row1.get(COLUMN_TO_SORT).compareTo(row2.get(COLUMN_TO_SORT));
            return 0;
        }
    });

    for (Iterator<List<String>> iterator = records.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }    
}   

private static List<String> getRecordFromLine(String row, String delimiter) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (Scanner rowScanner = new Scanner(row)) {
        rowScanner.useDelimiter(delimiter);
        while (rowScanner.hasNext()) {
            values.add(rowScanner.next());
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

** *Note that the example file is separated by comma, but in the code you use semicolon as the delimiter.*